# Flash AS2 one sound at a time

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, cs4

i'm creating a soundboard in Flash AS2, and i need that only one sound plays at a time, so if i play button 1, and then press button 2, button 1 sound stops and i listen to button 2 only. i'm making a test with 6 buttons, all of them in the same frame. i've found many answers responding that i would need to use on (press) {stopAllSounds () ; } on each button. so i did that, but now all sounds, including the one i'm trying to play, are stopped. so i end up hearing nothing. any ideas on how to solve this?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the answer! just put this code on the frame where your sounds are located:

```
onMouseDown = function () {
stopAllSounds(); };
```

done.

Answer (score 0):

Put one sound into a timeline to one movieclip. And use stop and play.
So to stopAll but not current use an array wich content all movieclip sound avbove defined.

Comment: thanks man, but i didn't understand a thing, lol. i forgot to say that i'm a noob. so you mean to use every sound button on a different timeline?there are a lot, and i mean a lot of sounds....

Comment: yes create a one movieclip for one sound drag then sound into his timeline and use play stop

Comment: well, ok thanks. if i can't find another answer i may have to do that.